# xslt - how to delete text after /

Tags: xml, xslt

I created `xslt` template for modify structure `xml` feed.

I get categories name:

```
 <xsl:element name="category">
<xsl:value-of select="catname"/>
  </xsl:element>
```

after generate file, xml look like:

```
<category>1400/5455/8788</category>
```

I want convert and remove text after / so finally I want display:

```
<category>1400</category>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the substring-before() XPath function.

```
<xsl:element name="category">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(catname,'/')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Reference with examples : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before